# Endpoint call using heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, heroku-api

I have deployed my backend on heroku,

https://morning-tor-91556.herokuapp.com/

when go to this link its working fine but now I want to call my endpoint /skills which is I have made in nodeJS in my backend the code is

```
app.get("/skills",function(req,res){
    Skill.find(function(err,foundSkills){
      if(!err){
        res.send(foundSkills);
        console.log(foundSkills);
      }else{
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

https://morning-tor-91556.herokuapp.com/skills

but when I go to this link its just loading rather then the response which I should get from get request but if I go to localhost:9000/skills I got my collection as I required.

so any idea what can I do.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in the database configuration, you should share the full code regarding it.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/deeta-max/portfolio/blob/master/server.js

Comment: but I dont think problem is there as its working fine if its run on local only problem  when running on heroku